# How do you use the appropriate color class for the current platform?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to share my Scene Kit code across iOS and OS X, but the API calls that accept colors (and images) take either UIColor/UIImage or NSColor/NSImage depending on the platform. How do I create the right class in Swift without duplicating the code?

Comment: SpriteKit's `SKColor` should do the trick

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use conditional compilation and type aliases:

```
#if os(OSX)
    typealias Color = NSColor
    typealias Image = NSImage
#else
    typealias Color = UIColor
    typealias Image = UIImage
#endif
```

Then use Color instead of UIColor or NSColor:

```
self.gameView!.backgroundColor = Color(red: 0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1)
```

---

Edit 2016-01-17: As DDPWNAGE noted above, Apple has created [`SKColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/macro/SKColor) with basically the same definition.

Comment: Just beware that `NSColor` and `UIColor` share some, but not all of their API... Ditto `NSImage`/`UIImage`. Since working with CF-style types is easier in Swift, you might consider using those in cross-platform code.

Comment: very ver useful i like it i really appreciate it thank u so much i love you