# How to use UIColor and NSColor simultaneously?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos

A note before I ask my question, to avoid being marked as a dupe: I've looked all over. A lot of the questions that are of a similar topic are in Objective-C and use Objective-C macros to fix this problem up.

A brief description:

`UIColor` is iOS's way of defining color, and `NSColor` is Mac OS's way. Reason being, it has to deal with the history behind Apple and Objective-C.

I want to make a game for iOS and Mac OS X. I made an Xcode project, in Swift, with build targets for iOS and Mac OS X.

One integral part of a game is being able to use/manipulate colors, be it for setting backgrounds, drawing sprites/gradients programmatically, drawing shapes... there's so much more.

My problem starts with the fact that I have to use `NSColor` for Mac and `UIColor` for iOS.

---

I've attempted making a class, `Color`, that is part of both build targets. I also have a class, `ColorExtension`, which `Color` subclasses, that subclasses `NSColor` on Mac OS and `UIColor` on iOS.

The result is, I'm able to use methods such as `Color.yellowColor()` just fine. However, problems begin to settle in when I have to use convenience initializers for `Color` such as

```
Color(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)
```

Those convenience initializers **don't inherit** to the `Color` class, so I get problems all over the place when I try to do something like that.

*I wish to be able to use these convenience initializers so I can have rendered color out of millions of colors, and not just the easy to use few.*

I've seen Objective-C macros `#define` it to be `UIColor` on iOS and `NSColor` on Mac, by [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15324304/2089760):

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
-(void)createColor:(UIColor*)color;

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
-(void)createColor:(NSColor*)color;

#endif
```

However, Swift doesn't support Objective-C macros, so that way's a no-go.

---

My code so far for defining color:

### `Color`

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit // only imported so I can try out stuff

class Color : ColorExtension {

}
```

### `ColorExtension` (Mac)

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

class ColorExtension : NSColor {

}
```

### `ColorExtension` (iOS)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ColorExtension : UIColor {

}
```

Comment: Did you see this: [How do you use the appropriate color class for the current platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108586/how-do-you-use-the-appropriate-color-class-for-the-current-platform) ?

Comment: In addition to what Martin R linked, since you're already importing SpriteKit, you can use [SKColor](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/macro/SKColor), which effectively just does this for you.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Have all of my upvotes. I've never heard of `SKColor`.

Comment: You could expand upon `#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#elseif os(OSX)
    import AppKit
#endif`

Comment: @Grimxn I got the code I posted in the Objective-C `#define` statements from the answer I linked above the snippet. However, `SKColor` will work for what I'm trying to do