# Function declaration for platform specific code in SWIFT

Tags: swift, cross-platform, declaration

How can I use platform specific function declarations in swift. My code in objective-C is working fine and looks like this:

```
#if !TARGET_OS_IPHONE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)TitleString withColor:(NSColor *) textColor {
#else
-(void) setTitle:(NSString *)TitleString withColor:(UIColor *) textColor {
#endif
```

But in swift when I try to make the same I receive compiler error messages. The code I try is this:

```
#if os(OSX)
func setTitle(TitleString titleString:String, WithColor textColor:NSColor) {
#else
func setTitle(TitleString titleString:String, WithColor textColor:UIColor) {
#endif
```

In this case I have an error at the #else. If I remove the first {, than I get error message at the #endif line.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108586/how-do-you-use-the-appropriate-color-class-for-the-current-platform ... or use `SKColor`.

Comment: This is a good idea. However it would be interesting how the declarations could be platform dependent. Somehow I have missed the SKColor solution.